# fisheye/crucible :failed to setup git executable

Tags: git, installation, executable, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

when I try to setup git executable to add git repo

It always give me failure info:!Invalid git executable: Unable to get git version

I check that the git executable exactly exists and can be executed by the user used to run crucible&fisheye

I check that the owner of git executable is the user used to run crucible&fisheye

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly due to the failure in setting the Git Executable Path. Please set the path for the Git Executable by following the insruction available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Git+client)

Answer (score 0):

set Git executable :/usr/local/bin/git

Answer (score 0):

I solved in Windows it by giving permissions to *Everyone* entity on the folder where *Git* is installed:

- Right click in the folder where Git is installed and then select Properties.
- In the properties window click on the Security tab then click on Edit.
- On the Permissions window click on the Add button to open the Select Users Group or Groups window.
- On the Select Users or Groups window you can enter Everyone.
- Then, click Ok.
- Select Full Control by placing a check mark on “Allow”.
- Apply the settings.
- Close the properties window.

Then, you can put the Git path in *Fisheye*.

This error occurs because *Atlassian Fisheye* service was started by *NETWORK_SERVICE* user, and this user wasn´t able to access to the folder where *git.exe* file is.